Is there a MatrixSymbol version of complex=True?
In order to solve equations like (x+conjugate(x)=0), Sympy needs you to tell it that x is a complex variable, e.g.
x = symbols('x', complex=True)
solve((x-conjugate(x)).as_real_imag(),x)

The output to this is [{x: re(x), im(x): 0}], i.e. x can be any purely real value. I want to do something analogous with a matrix equation, e.g.
n=2
X = MatrixSymbol('x',n,n,complex=True)
solve((X-conjugate(X)).as_real_imag(),X)

However, MatrixSymbol does not support complex=True.
What kind of alternative is there? Should I just create n^2 variables (each instantiated with complex=True), and build my own matrix out of these, rather than use a MatrixSymbol object? How can I scale that up when n gets larger, i.e. n=5?
